# If ad−bc= α, then what is A^−1, in terms of α?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $ad−bc= \alpha$, then what is $A^{−1}$, in terms of $\alpha$? *Note that the $\alpha$ and $a$ are seperate variables.*

I tried with some numbers for matrix $A$. For example I used: \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&9\end{bmatrix}
and I got $1$ as the determinant.

The inverse of $A$ I found was \begin{bmatrix}9&-2\\-4&1\end{bmatrix}

I still don't unterstand the relationship between $\alpha = 1$ and $A^{-1}$. Could someone help please explain this one?

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be a $2 \times 2$ matrix?  Try some more examples; some with determinant not $1$.

Comment: A is a nxn matrix it doesn't necessarily have to be a 2 x 2. Thanks GEdgar

Comment: Thanks for the link Randall I think that helps answer this question.

Comment: A nontrivial relation is $\det A^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks so much janmarqz!